# Discord webhook embed php curl not working anymore after recent Discord update

Tags: php, curl, discord

I've had this Discord webhook for a long time, and everything was alright. Now suddenly it stopped working. The error I'm receiving is:

> {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}

While the message **and** an embed is set. Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/1234567890/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$hookObject = json_encode([
    "content" => "New sellers application!",
    "username" => "Roblox",
    "avatar_url" => "https://www.roblox.com/headshot-thumbnail/image?userId=1&width=420&height=420&format=png",
    "tts" => false,
    "embeds" => [
        [
            "title" => "Accept",
            "type" => "rich",
            "description" => "",
            "url" => "https://google.com/",
            "timestamp" => gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time()),
            "color" => hexdec( "02b757" ),
            "author" => [
                "name" => "REMOVED",
                "url" => "REMOVED"
            ],
            "fields" => [
                [
                    "name" => "Discord",
                    "value" => "REMOVED#0563",
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Amount per week",
                    "value" => 30000,
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Email",
                    "value" => "REMOVED@example.com",
                    "inline" => false
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Name",
                    "value" => "hehe",
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Roblox username",
                    "value" => "Roblox",
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Roblox link",
                    "value" => "https://www.roblox.com/users/1/profile",
                    "inline" => false
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "Decline ->",
                    "value" => "https://google.com/api/decseller?id=JUSTTESTJUSTTEST",
                    "inline" => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
echo $hookObject;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $hookObject,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Length" => strlen($hookObject),
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ]
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
echo "Body -> ";
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
var_dump($body);
curl_close($ch);
```

That code returns the following:

```
{"content":"New sellers application!","username":"Roblox","avatar_url":"https://www.roblox.com/headshot-thumbnail/image?userId=1&width=420&height=420&format=png","tts":false,"embeds":[{"title":"Accept","type":"rich","description":"","url":"https://google.com/","timestamp":"2019-12-10T10:23:33","color":178007,"author":{"name":"REMOVED","url":"REMOVED"},"fields":[{"name":"Discord","value":"REMOVED#0563","inline":true},{"name":"Amount per week","value":"30000","inline":true},{"name":"Email","value":"REMOVED@example.com","inline":false},{"name":"Name","value":"hehe","inline":true},{"name":"Roblox username","value":"Roblox","inline":true},{"name":"Roblox link","value":"https://www.roblox.com/users/1/profile","inline":false},{"name":"Decline ->","value":"https://google.com/api/decseller?id=JUSTTESTJUSTTEST","inline":false}]}]}* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 5 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
*   Trying 162.159.134.233...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149992 ms for 3 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x1c517af4500)
* Connected to discordapp.com (162.159.134.233) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain; CN=ssl711320.cloudflaressl.com
*  start date: Sep  5 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 13 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1c517af4500)
> POST /api/webhooks/1234567890/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ HTTP/2
Host: discordapp.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 859
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 400
< date: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 10:23:39 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 58
< set-cookie: __cfduid=dc03695b32b9ae182c651991a4b50bbe51575973419; expires=Thu, 09-Jan-20 10:23:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< x-ratelimit-bucket: 3cd1f278bd0ecaf11e0d2391374c011d
< x-ratelimit-limit: 5
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 4
< x-ratelimit-reset: 1575973422
< x-ratelimit-reset-after: 2
< via: 1.1 google
< alt-svc: clear
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 542e812f4e54d905-AMS
<
* Connection #0 to host discordapp.com left intact
Body -> string(58) "{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}"
```

I asked on Reddit, people couldn't help me there (apparently), and I asked it at the following Discord guilds:

- Discord Official API
- The Coding Den

But no one could help there as well, so I'm 100% relying on you guys now, the documentation about the Discord webhooks -> https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Shouldn't `description` in your embed object should be non-empty? I am pretty sure that that is the actual message. See [Discord Webhook](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/discord_webhook.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send in **content-type** now, there's no error and disord didn't mentioned this on their documentation.

Content-length seems optional now but maybe later on they might require that too.

```
<?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        // 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    ));
```

Comment: if the programmer does not manually specify Content-Length, libcurl will automatically generate the header on CURLOPT_POST requests. and its safer to let curl generate the header automatically (curl wont make any typos or forget a space or something, they have testsuites to make sure of that, but a programmer might forget a space or make a typo or something) rule of thumb: don't make the Content-Length header yourself, let libcurl do it for you.

Comment: My answer is specific to discord, maybe their server most likely is requiring it. our bots stopped working so I tried with and without suppling content-type. and that was our issue then.

Comment: i'm just commenting on your ```Content-length seems optional now but maybe later on they might require that too.```, not "Content-Type", you should not supply the Content-Length manually ^^ libcurl will do it for you if you don't do it yourself.

Comment: @AaronJonk Try trimming down your function to a basic simple message and mix it with the content-type json and see if it works. its also possible the issue is UTF8 on 1 of the variables. also remove your "length" header part.